# upgrade to 12.4 - multi-monitors go bad

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, monterey, thunderbolt-display

MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

Updated to 12.4 this AM - I have a CalDigit TS3 USB-C docking station, with 2 external monitors (3 total screens) - previously this worked great. Now one of the screens is bad Samsung

By bad I mean: Comes on - about 1 second, then goes black, for some period between 8 to 30 seconds. Its not a power cycle, because when the screen comes on the complete image is valid and good. If it was power cycling, the screen would be warming up. Filling or something like that.

I have no means to debug this, and no means to "go backwards" - this is not very good for me as the external monitor is effectively my primary monitor I sit in front of.

Reseated all cables, etc.  Used a different (work DELL laptop) and it works just fine problem only occurs with MAC + Monterey 12.4.

the ONLY change was to install the 12.4 update

```
C34J79x:
  Resolution:   4096 x 2304
  UI Looks like:    2048 x 1152 @ 60.00Hz
  Framebuffer Depth:    30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
  Display Serial Number:    HTJK800082  
  Mirror:   On
  Mirror Status:    Hardware Mirror
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
  Connection Type:  Thunderbolt/DisplayPort
```

Comment: Does the display work correctly when connected directly to the Mac (i.e. removing the Hub?)

Comment: Not possible to do that now - currently display port cables. Will try later today - I can use USB C only if/when I re-cable everything, not was to do at this moment. And in the end, that is not an acceptable solution (cable reasons)

Comment: It's not a solution, but a test, to see whether the hub is a factor.

Comment: yea - it works if it is direct.  Earlier today - I had a situation where it worked but when I turned the HDMI Tv back on it stopped. However it was in a weird overscan mode AND I CANNOT REPRODUCE THAT WORKING STATE AGAIN... What I mean is this: I left everything plugged in. Walked away for about 3..4 hrs, TV on wall shut down (powered off) and the Samsung monitor was working mostly correctly.  The title bar (ie: <apple> Finder File Edit menu) was it only half visible and off screen - but I cannot seem to reproduce that situation again. Keep point: TV on => flashing again.

Comment: To be more clear:  MAC -> Direct USB C to Samsung monitor works. I cannot do monitor + docking station (I have only 1 usb-c cable) the Samsung monitor is normally attached via Display port to the back of the CalDigit TS3. I have a TCL tv on the wall, it is connected to the small rectangular display port (old MAC pro had this) then to an HDMI adapter to the TCL TV